# Equivalence relation problem - discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having issues trying to start this question, what does defining a new relation mean?

The question:
Suppose $\rho$ is reflexive and transitive relation on a set S. Define a new relation $\sigma$ as follows: $a \sigma b$ is true if and only if both $a\rho b$ and $b\rho a$ are true. Show that $\sigma$ is an equivalence relation.

Thanks for any help

Comment: They are telling you what the definition of the new relation is. Your task is to prove it is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

*$a\sigma a$ because $a\rho a$

*$a\sigma b$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $a\rho b$ and $b\rho a$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $b\rho a$ and $a\rho b$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $b\sigma a$

*$a\sigma b$ and $b\sigma c$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $a\rho b$ and $b\rho c$ and $b\rho a$ and $c\rho b$ $\Rightarrow$ $a\rho c$ and $c\rho a$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $a\sigma c$